# How does the distribution of floor choices of your co-passengers affect your time of arrival in an elevator?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity, time, everyday-life

*Note: This is a wiki post.*

Suppose you are late for a meeting and you have to take an elevator. The floor choice of your fellow passengers influences how late you will reach your destination. If everyone gets off at a later floor, it's perfect. But unfortunately,  it doesn't happen like that so often. The most likely scenario, some people get off sooner than you, and some get off later. Let's ignore the ones that get off later because they don't affect your time of arrival.

Looking only at the other set of people, what distribution of their floor choices is favorable, and what is unfavorable for you? Remember, every second counts!

<sub>Context: I am practicing some visual methods to answer questions that are otherwise difficult to explain using words. I will be using them in my teaching assignments. Suggestions and constructive comments are welcome. If you believe you can do better, please feel free to do so by posting your answers.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the rate of acceleration and deceleration of the elevator is the same. You start at $t=0\:$.

This is the velocity time graph of the lift when there is only one passenger (you).

[image]

In this case, you reach your destination at $t=T_0$.

The graph looks like a neat trapezium. The area of this graph gives you the distance traveled, and that is the same regardless of how many stops you have in between.

$$\int_0^{t} v\:dt=x_t-x_0 = \textbf{constant}$$

Now consider the case when there is one more passenger, and that passenger gets off in the middle.

[image]

In this case you reach your destination at $t=T_1>T_0$.

Notice how the stop in between leads to a triangular hole in the middle. **So the graph has to now shift towards the right, to keep the area constant**. Now regardless of where you move around the hole left and right, as long as it doesn't overlap with the left and right edges of the trapezium, you will arrive at $t=T_1$.

Now consider the case when the second passenger decides to get off just one floor above. This time the hole overlaps with the left edge of the trapezium.

[image]

In this case you reach your destination at $t=T_2 \:\text{and}\: T_0<T_2<T_1$.

Notice this time the hole is smaller in size, and the trapezium doesn't need to compensate as much as it had for case 2.

So we learned that more overlap leads to smaller holes and that in turn leads to lesser compensation and faster arrival times.

**Hence a staggered distribution will be the most unfavorable, and the ones clustered around the starting and ending floors are most favorable.**

[image]

Comment: If you assume there is enough distance between floors such that the elevator achieves maximum velocity even when starting and stopping on adjecent floors, then none of the arrangements matter and the total time delay is simply proportional to the number of stops, correct? And this answer is saying "it's better to not make it up to full speed if you're going to have to stop multiple times" and rather "it's better to maximize the time at full speed"

Comment: Perhaps the latter is exactly your solution. You want the time-averaged velocity to be as high as possible (ie the shortest time for a given distance)